# 2013 BMW electronic oil level check fails to complete

Tags: oil, bmw, electronics, diy

My wife's car is a 2013 BMW 335i with M-Sport package.  The engine has no dipstick so the only way to check the oil level is using the menu-driven display.  However, this never completes.  Specifically, when I start, the screen looks like this:
[image]
Then it seems to attempt to do what it's supposed to do for a while:
[image]
But it never seems to complete.  In particular, the percent complete goes to somewhere between 17% and 30% I think, and then reverts to the first screen.
There is a separate menu item which is to *display* the oil level and it shows this:
[image]

### Questions

The car is new to me, and the manual is somewhat vague on what is supposed to happen.  So my questions are:

1. Shouldn't this go to 100% and show an actual oil level?
2. If that's correct, is this possible to fix at home, or is this dealer-only territory?
3. Any clues as to how to go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

According to this video (at the very end)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDBnBVAvHBA

there's an indication of the oil level.

I have to ask: Have you *ever* seen this "finish" on this car?
I'm thinking it might be a software version issue.  You can get to that via that display and ask your dealer if there's an upgrade.

Comment: No, I've never seen it finish.  I upgraded the firmware to the latest available days after I bought it.  [That firmware](https://legacy.bmw.com/_common/shared/owners/bluetooth/pdf/Readme_UPD01008_ENG.pdf) only appears to have been a patch to the entertainment portion.